# Не работает регулярное выражение из переменной

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match_all("@>(.*?)<@u", $irew, $out2, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($irew);
print_r($out2); 

<a href="/models/philips/gc2528.html">GC2528</a>Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

Что самое интересное, если мы видеоизменим регулярное выражение, вместо переменной подставив прямой текст, то все отлично работает. Что за магия?

```
preg_match_all("@>(.*?)<@u", '<a href="/models/philips/gc2528.html">GC2528</a>', $out2, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($out2); 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => >GC2528< ) [1] => Array ( [0] => GC2528 ) )
```

Comment: Чтобы избавиться от тегов - достаточно применить strip_tags.

Comment: @u_mulder, это ничего не даст, если будет среди другого `html` или обычного текста? Что больше вероятно, что так и есть.

Comment: Судя по исходной регулярке (а не той что в ответе) дело было именно в тексте между тегами.

Answer (score -1):

```
$html = '<a href="/models/philips/gc2528.html">GC4</a><a href="/models/philips/gc2528.html">GC3</a> texttetx
    <a href="/models/philips/gc2528.html">GC2</a>
    text
<a href="/models/philips/gc2528.html">GC1</a>';
$array =[];
preg_match_all('@<a[^>]+>\K.+?(?=</a>)@u', $html, $array);
var_dump($array);
```

Вывод:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "GC4"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "GC3"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "GC2"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "GC1"
  }
}
```